# Is there a "More options" (vertical ellipsis) menu component in Framework7?

Tags: html-framework-7

Is there an equivalent for the "more options menu" (those three vertical dots) in Framework7? Can i achieve that behavior with any of the existing components?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with a [popover component](http://framework7.io/docs/popover.html).